# Matplotlib does not draw the last line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that takes a list of tuples with float values, from the list I make two new separate lists, each containing the vertex coordinates of the triangle. Then I use matplotlib to draw the vertices.

```
def draw_figure(list_of_floats):
    
x_coord, y_coord = zip(*list_of_floats)
x_coord = list(x_coord)
y_coord = list(y_coord)

# print("Coordinates:")
# for item in x_coord:
#     print(item)
# for item in y_coord:
#     print(item)

# Plot the triangle
plt.plot(x_coord, y_coord)

# Set the plot limits
plt.xlim(min(x_coord) - 1, max(x_coord) + 1)
plt.ylim(min(y_coord) - 1, max(y_coord) + 1)
```

But instead of three lines, the library draws two. I tried adding:

```
 plt.plot(x_coord, y_coord, x_coord[0], y_coord[1])
```

So that it had to draw a third line to the beginning, but it did not work too.

[image: The image of triangle with only 2 lines]

How do I supposed to fix this?

Comment: we cannot see the data you are posting. please change your code to add hardcoded data that reproduces the problem

Comment: Hi @Kadel, could you please edit your question, so it would be a [Minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example)?
It would be nice to add imports, reformat code, so it looks properly and add the data you're using as well.
Ideally, people should be able to simply copy-paste your code and be able to run it.

Comment: if you want to close it, you need to add the first point again at the end of your list of coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the initial `(x,y)` coordinate at the end:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_figure(list_of_floats):
    x_coord, y_coord = zip(*list_of_floats)
    x_coord = list(x_coord)
    y_coord = list(y_coord)

    # THIS: add initial point
    x_coord.append(x_coord[0])
    y_coord.append(y_coord[0])

    # Plot the triangle
    plt.plot(x_coord, y_coord)

    # Set the plot limits
    plt.xlim(min(x_coord) - 1, max(x_coord) + 1)
    plt.ylim(min(y_coord) - 1, max(y_coord) + 1)
```

I tested with the following data:

```py
draw_figure([[1, 2], [3, -1], [2.5, 5]])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Do check with the below noted points :**

1. Make sure that you have included all the necessary data in your plot. It's possible that you are accidentally excluding the last point or line in your data.
2. Check the limits of your x-axis and y-axis. If the limits are not set properly, the last line may not be visible. You can try adjusting the limits using the xlim() and ylim() functions.
3. Try calling the show() function at the end of your code to make sure that the plot is fully rendered. Sometimes the plot window may not update automatically, and calling show() can force it to update.